# Is redis pub/sub an alternative of sockets?

Tags: sockets, websocket, redis

I am new to redis and while reading about I got to know pub/sub. I found many similarities between pub/sub and socket. I googled the same question but didn't get any satisfactory answer. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

Sockets and *pub/sub* are **fundamentally very different**.

- **Topology** - Sockets are point-to-point, i.e. one-to-one. *Pub/sub* is many-to-many, i.e. M-to-N where M and N are potentially different and either could be zero, so you could be sending messages that no-one is listening to, or listening for messages that no-one is sending.
- **Broker** - *Pub/sub* requires the presence of a **broker** to forward/retain/retry messages and manage publishers and subscribers. There is no broker involved in sockets.
- **Message Orientation** - **Pub/sub** is message-oriented, so if a publisher sends a 10 or 80 byte message, the subscriber(s) receive exactly 10 or 80 bytes. Sockets are *"stream-oriented"*, so there is no built-in demarcation of the end of a message - just a stream of bytes. So, a client socket could send 1000 bytes, then another 1,000 bytes yet the receiver could receive 10 bytes, then 3 bytes, then 1,987 bytes.
- **Synchronicity** - Sockets are essentially synchronous, so the receiver has to be there to interact at the same time the sender is sending. *Pub/sub* is more asynchronous in nature, a publisher could send a message and the broker could retain it and send it later when a new client connects, so the sender and receiver aren't necessarily around at the same time.
- **Persistence** - Data sent on a socket is ephemeral, it is not stored anywhere unless one of the two end-points decides to store it. *Pub/sub* messages may be stored and persisted by the broker, for logging or retries or to notify newly connecting clients of the last known status of some publisher.

Comment: I agree most of what you said until I l learn zeromq pub/sub socket because zeromq brands itself as brokerless.

Comment: I asked a related question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70077299/zmq-router-dealer-usefulness-over-message-broker   Can you take a look ?

Comment: @Qiulang邱朗 I will take a look and have a think - though zeromq is not a forte of mine.