# ZMQ Router/Dealer usefulness over message broker

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, zeromq, messaging, messagebroker

When using message queue I am used to the message broker model, e.g. RabbitMQ or Redis pub/sub, so zeromq's **brokerless** model feels a bit "unnatural".

The router/dealer model and the [routing envelopes](http://wiki.zeromq.org/sandbox:dealer) concept strike me as the typical message broker elements, e.g. in RabbitMQ.

Could someone please provide a real-world example of using zmq router/dealer over a message broker (except for the obvious one that I don't need to set up a broker)?

BTW, the question also applies to zeromq pub/sub pattern.

[image: router/dealer]

Answer (score 1):

You might want to distribute work to multiple workers, over a very fast channel (e.g.: Unix sockets), without the extra-overhead introduced by a broker. One use case for us: we split video files into images that are sent to a set of workers, each worker being bound to a GPU.

We don't need persistence, we don't need security, we don't need message transformation, we don't need protocol and transport conversion ... all features usually provided by a message broker, at a cost. We just want to distribute work as fast as possible. Using zmq, we keep the possibility to distribute work over multiple machines just by changing the protocol/connection string. We then have to find the balance between doing all locally on N GPUs, or distributing works on multiple machines with N x X GPUs.

See zmq as a "broker construction kit", allowing you to easily build a lightweight broker tailored to your specific needs.

Comment: But "distribute work to multiple workers" sounds like the push/pull pattern in zeromq

Comment: Yes. That's the strength of zmq: you combine the patterns you need to build a broker that covers your exact needs.

Comment: For someone used to the broker concepts I keep asking why. For example, like I said in my question, zeromq pub/sub pattern is another why.

Comment: But it seems that the answer all come down to your words "a broker construction kit" without a real broker.

Comment: Exactly. In most realistic scenarios where there is a large set of connected “nodes” (threads, processes or boxes), there is a need for centralized intermediaries that sit on the network and properly store/route/filter/wrap messages, according to some routing/filtering/wrapping algorithm/strategy.

In those type of scenarios, you’ll have to write the broker yourself, using the building blocks that ZeroMQ provides.

Comment: However, unlike “heavy weight” messaging systems which implement everything but the kitchen sink (at a cost in term of deployment, complexity, administration and performance), you can tailor your custom broker to your exact specific needs.